# Restaurant rating information in China

Tags: online-resources, food-and-drink, china, restaurants

I'd like to try to find places to eat in China. In the USA I look on Chowhound, which has a pretty good user base. Is there a similar tool for China?

I could use a site like TripAdvisor, but I worry the average TripAdvisor user is looking for an experience with dragons on the walls and gold leaf everywhere and a courteous waiter, and would give a place a bad review if the food was too spicy or the place was dingy, even if the food was great.

Are there any sites like this?

Comment: Concering TripAdvisor: While I was travelling around Sri Lanka, I found it very helpful. The hostel and restaurant reviews were usually on mark. You might have to read 10-15 reviews to look for a common denominator (or to see if it really was just somebody who didn't like the spicy food ;)).
Although, of course, I do not know how TripAdvisor works for China.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you enter the city and restaurant into Baidu you can find lots of reviews. Of course you have to use Chinese (copy and paste works). Here's an example from Shenzhen (I think it's a hot pot restaurant):

http://meishi.qq.com/shops/13400196635890174326#shop_pro_comment#bd=baidu_map

One of many reviews in Chinese:
其实还不错，去过几次了，来了个新鲜种类，清凉型锅底，加柠檬的还可以啊。
就是服务员记性不太好，点了个羊排到快走了的时候才来。有点油腻。

Google translate thinks it says: 
Actually pretty good, went several times to the kind of fresh, cool type of pot, lemon also can ah. Memory is not very good waiter, ordered a lamb chops to brisk walking time to come. A little greasy.

They paid Y50 per person, and gave it an overall rating of 4/5 stars.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't read Chinese, I suggest you use FourSquare, they have decent amount of info in the big cities.

If you do read some Chinese, try [Dianping](http://www.dianping.com), they are the FourSquare in china and has the most complete listing of restaurants. It has both iOS and android apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try a city specific expat-focused website.  Shenzhen Party, Shanghaiist, Beijinger, etc etc.
Lots of Engl language content about the eateries around town.